# How do i display redis erros on the front end i.e React js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have an api that I implemented Redis Rate Limiting. On limit the API returns error code 503 and sets retry-after. Now i would want to show this to the users whenever the Limit is reached on the front End am using React js.
I tried this but didnt work for me:

```
return toast.error("Retry After", {
position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
});
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I fixed it by making sure i catch the error from the back end and use the specific error code to show relevant error messages to the front end.